# Bonanza Api: Can't get token working to work in php

Tags: php, api

I am following the examples provided => [Bonanza Api Examples](http://api.bonanza.com/docs/examples/php)

I am trying to test on a 'addFixedPriceItem' with this code:

```
<?php

    $dev_name = "************";
    $cert_name = "************";

    $url = "https://api.bonanza.com/api_requests/secure_request";
    $headers = array("X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME: " . $dev_name, "X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME: " . $cert_name);
    $args = array();
    $post_fields = "fetchTokenRequest";
    echo "Request: $post_fields <BR>";
    $connection = curl_init($url);
    $curl_options = array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$headers, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post_fields,
                    CURLOPT_POST=>1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1);  # data will be returned as a string
    curl_setopt_array($connection, $curl_options);
    $json_response = curl_exec($connection);
    if (curl_errno($connection) > 0) {
      echo curl_error($connection) . "<BR>";
      exit(2);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response,true);
    $token = $response['fetchTokenResponse']['authToken'];
    echo "Token: $token <BR>";

    $item['title'] = "My Item";
    $item['price'] = 30.57;
    $item['quantity'] = 1;
    $item['description'] = "This item is great.  Any html here.";
    $item['pictureDetails']['pictureURL'] = "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png";
    $item['primaryCategory']['categoryId'] = 377;
    $item['shippingDetails']['shippingServiceOptions']['freeShipping'] = true;
    $args = array("item" => $item);
    $args['requesterCredentials']['bonanzleAuthToken'] = $token;

    $post_fields = "addFixedPriceItem=" .  urlencode(json_encode($args));
    echo "Request: $post_fields <BR>";

    $curl_options2 = array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$headers, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$post_fields,
                    CURLOPT_POST=>1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1);  # data will be returned as a string
    curl_setopt_array($connection, $curl_options2);
    $json_response = curl_exec($connection);
    if (curl_errno($connection) > 0) {
      echo curl_error($connection) . "<BR>";
      exit(2);
    }
    curl_close($connection);
    $response = json_decode($json_response,true);
    $itemId= $response['addFixedPriceItemResponse']['itemId'];
    echo "itemId: $itemId <BR>";


    echo "Response: <BR>";
    echo "<PRE>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</PRE>";


    ?>
```

Response:

```
Array
(
    [ack] => Failure
    [version] => 1.0beta
    [timestamp] => 2015-12-23T00:11:53.000Z
    [errorMessage] => Array
        (
            [message] => Bonapitit::TokenNotVerified
        )

)
```

Seems like the token is not working, anyone had experience with Bonanza can please help?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you got solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your token is not working because it has not been verified.

The [fetchToken](http://api.bonanza.com/docs/reference/fetch_token) response should include "authenticationURL", which goes to a Bonanza login page. Logging in from there will verify the token for the Bonanza user who logged in.

Token verification is how Bonanza knows you have a Bonanza user's permission to do things like add items on their behalf or view their private sales information